# Adding permanent routes and IP, MASK to second interface

Tags: networking, centos, routing, ifconfig

I'm using following commands to add to my second interface different settings:

```
ifconfig eth4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ifconfig eth4 netmask 255.255.255.240
ifconfig eth4 broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

   // note: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx are just a example. 
   // I'm using real IP's on the system
```

The problem is when I reboot the system I'm loosing this settings. In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` I have two files `ifcfg-eth1` which is staying after reboot.. no problems at all and `ifcfg-eth4` which loose above settings.

**ifcfg-eth1** main interface

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth1
UUID=fd037d95-4aea-4d7d-9a62-d8c621aee6e6
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR= // I've removed it for the question
IPADDR0= xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
PREFIX0=26
GATEWAY0= xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

**ifcfg-eth4**

```
HWADDR= // I've removed it for the question
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth4
UUID=3a2460d0-5068-45d2-8105-271a10d4ae77
ONBOOT=no
```

So I've tried to setup same configuration like on `ifcfg-eth1` like this

```
HWADDR= // I've removed it for the question
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth4
UUID=3a2460d0-5068-45d2-8105-271a10d4ae77
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR0=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
BROADCAST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Changes here are

```
ONBOOT=yes // from no -> yes
IPADDR0=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx // other IP
NETMASK=255.255.255.240 // other mask
BROADCAST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx // broadcast addr
```

When I run

```
service network restart
```

it hangs and eventually got [no] .. when I remove addition settings it's restarting the network normally.

So how can I make this permanent and not needing to add it on each reboot? What I'm missing?

I'm using **CentOS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
HWADDR= // I've removed it for the question
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth4
UUID=3a2460d0-5068-45d2-8105-271a10d4ae77
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
BROADCAST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Note `BOOTPROTO` and after this of course

```
service network restart
```

You may even reboot if you need to test